# Hair appearing at origin point of mesh

Tags: particles, hair

So I have this [towel render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnEwX.jpg); everything seems to look fine about it, except that little distracting point of floating fur at the top which just ruins it.

[image]

Looking a tiny bit into the scene, I found the hair is built at exactly the origin point, and changing it will render the hair in the set place.

I could surely move the origin point out of the camera, but if I wanted to rotate it, scale it or animate it in a way that involves it, it'd be really important to have it in the appropriate location, meaning the hair will have to be rendered there as well.

So what exactly causes the hair to just... appear there?

Here are the [particle settings](https://i.gyazo.com/679f04c8d2fe35c09d4079c8cfb411b6.mp4) if that matters BTW.

**Edit:** Here's the .blend file for more clarity, though this is a pretty small issue: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bejfakblkf8ntuj/extowel.zip?dl=0

Comment: Isn't that "floating fur" just the object origin? I can't see anything else there... can you show a close-up render of that zone, so to be sure it's visible?

Comment: The floating fur is visible in the "towel render" link, the second image is just there to show that indeed that floating fur point is being built at the origin point.

Comment: oh yes, now I get it, sorry (I thought that was a reference..:D).. weird... if nothing works, try sharing the file, if possible (preferably through http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) as the setup is not easy to reproduce...

Comment: If I had to guess (which I do because the link doesn't work, it just takes me to my dropbox)  I'd say you have some rogue geometry at that spot, you could select a vert, ctlr  L to select connected, ctrl i for inverse and x, and to try and delete it. That or you have an odd stack order with a cloth sim. Or post the blend for a real answer.  Really nice render btw.

Comment: The link is fixed now, btw, I've looked and couldn't find any geometry located in the origin point of the mesh. The cloth sim is already applied so I don't think that should be a problem.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, and somehow fixed it by checking "Use Modifier Stack" under the "Emissions" tab in the particles menu.

Alternatively, this was also solved when I went to the object modifiers menu and moved my particle system above my subsurf modifier.

(I know this is an old question but I came across it when I googled the same problem, so hopefully this helps someone else!)

Comment: Moving the particle system above the subsurf modifier is a bad idea, since then all particles are created on the unsubsurfed model. After this follows the subsurf modifier, and now some particles may not be correctly placed on the surface anymore.

*Use Modifier Stack* is the only correct approach, although I don't know why Blender does not behave this way by default.

Comment: "Use Modifier Stack" works fine for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I work with Blender 3.2.2 and I just had the very same problem. As suggested I searched for the 'Use Modifier Stack' option under the emissions tab in the particle settings but I could not find it. In my case I was using a subdivision surface modifier which came *after* the particle system in the modifier tab. I just rearranged the modifiers and **moved the subdivision modifier over the particle system to the top**. This solved the bug for me

Comment: The Use Modifier Stack option is in the Particle settings under Hair -> Source -> Use Modifier Stack.
Also its by no means a bug that the order of the Modifiers is importend for what you do. If you have a Plane and first Subsurf it and than Solidify it  you will get a roundet square with thicknes... if you do it the other way around, you will get a box with roundet corners. In the same logick, if your subdivisions happen after the Particle system, your hair will be emitted from faces that later are not there anymore. But Smoothed to another location